# Hardware TOTP system-on-chip with strongly guarded seed

Tags: hardware, totp, hardware-token, soc

I am looking for hardware TOTP system-on-chip, where it would not be possible for an adversary to extract the shared secret (TOTP seed in other words). I am researching an application, where one same seed has to be used in large number of hardware tokens for a long time.

The closest I could find is a chip for biometric passport, where there is a secret key burnt at manufacturing stage, so that it is not extractable yet used internally for signing or decryption - see "chip authentication" at https://www.readid.com/blog/cloning-detection-epassports.

Accordingly, I am looking for similar security level but different function (reliably hiding totp seed as opposed to identity). Could you please point me out to the right direction?

Comment: Use Secure Element chip to store the seed. This is what TOTP apps like Google authenticator do in Google Pixel.